# Checking whether an object is real JSONArray or JSONObject in Android/Java

Tags: java, android

I made some research and I found these two methods of checking, but I dont know which would be slower and cause more overhead?

Method 1:

```
public boolean isJSONValid(String test)
{
    try {
        new JSONObject(test);
        return true;
    } catch(JSONException ex) { 
        return false;
    }
}
```

Method 2:

```
if (Law.get("LawSet") instanceof JSONObject)
 {
    JSONObject Lawset = Law.getJSONObject("LawSet");                        
 }
 else if (Law.get("LawSet") instanceof JSONArray)
{
    JSONArray Lawset = Law.getJSONArray("LawSet");
}
```

**EDIT: Apparently both methods will not work according to the comments I got below this question, so how do I check whether the incoming string of characters is a valid JSONObject or a JSONArray?**

Comment: They are not comparable techniques. In the first case, you have a `String`. In the second case, you do not have a `String`.

Comment: cant I pass the JSON I get from the server to the first method?

Comment: Assuming that "the JSON [you] get from the server" is in the form of a `String`, then yes. That's usually the case. However, then the second method is useless, as there *you have already parsed the JSON*, otherwise you would not have instances of `JSONObject` and `JSONArray` as candidates.

Comment: well thats what Im trying to check against. Sometimes the server returns a JSON string but sometimes due to a server error it returns something like <br>...some php error here<br>, so I want to check whether what Im receiving is a json or a string

Comment: The second method you cite cannot do what you are asking, because to execute that code, *you have already parsed the JSON*.

Comment: so I'll be good using the first method? is there any other way I could make this check

Comment: "so I'll be good using the first method?" -- if it is a JSON object, yes. "is there any other way I could make this check" -- probably.

Comment: why would I check whether a JSON object is a JSON object

Comment: JSON can either be an array or an object. Your first method will fail if the string is not a JSON object. That means it will fail if the string is a JSON array, or if the string is not valid JSON.

Comment: so how can I modify it to not fail when the object is JSONOBject or JSONArray but fail if it is anything else?

Comment: Shouldn't you *know* whether your server is returning a JSON object rather than a JSON array? After all, you have to handle those differently when you go to use the JSON.

Comment: Well I wanted a no-brainer general method just to clear the HTML strings I get instead ofJSONWhatevers :)

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
String myData= "{ ... }";
Object json = new JSONTokener(myData).nextValue();
if (json instanceof JSONObject)
  //This is object
else if (json instanceof JSONArray)
  //This is array
```

It will work fine